# Notify owner when duplicated lead comes through web-to-lead form

Tags: duplicate-management, web2lead, notification

Salesforce is already doing a fine job stopping duplicated leads from being created through web-to-lead forms.

The only problem is that the only notification is a "Salesforce Could Not Create This Lead" email to the administrator.

I would like to notify the owner of the lead/contact (or even a static email if that's easier!) when this happens. Ideally, I would like to use a custom email template because the current notification is not easy to digest.

Comment: Hi Comly, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Would you mind updating your post to actually contain a question? That would make it more clearly on topic and easier to help you out!

Comment: Probably you should write a logic using APEX to trigger the email to static Email Id or to the lead owner/contact.